# О людях и человеках

Tags: этимология

Попалась информация, что слово "люди" - это сокращение от "любимые дети Бога". Но, по-моему, это что-то из серии трактовки слов, которую любит Сергей Алексеев (а он, в свою очередь почерпнул это еще от кого-то - сейчас не вспомню). Или это действительно так?
Но мне в любом случае интересно узнать происхождение слова "люди", и почему оно бывает только во множественном числе, а в единственном - "человек"?

Answer (score 2):

Задорнов еще больше любит. )))

Например, по-украински "людына" – человек. А "чоловик" – муж. Так что никаких божьих детей.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "люди" происходит от ПИЕ слова ***e̯leudhis*** "свободные люди, народ", от ***e̯leudheros*** "взрослый, свободный человек" (буквально - выросший).

Как видим, в слове ***e̯leudhis*** имеется суффикс -i-, который ошибочно был реинтерпретирован в русском языке как маркер множественного числа. А первоначально это часть основы.